# Phpmailer Fatal error: Class 'SMTP' not found in

Tags: php, phpmailer

Estoy intentado enviar un correo utilizando la clase phpmailer, sin embargo hasta el momento no lo he conseguido. He intentado varias opciones y combinaciones dentro del código e incluso ver si el problema no se encuentra en el archivo php.ini pero solo he conseguido lo siguiente.

> Fatal error: Class 'SMTP' not found in "c:\xampp\miruta\phpmailer\class.phpmailer.php on line 1520"

Hasta aquí lo que he conseguido concluir es que solo no encuentra la clase "**class.smtp.php**" por lo que de un inicio la incluí manualmente con un `include/require`, pero no funciono ya que al intentar enviar el correo se quedo colgada la petición y no envío nada.

Por otro lado encontré que estaba incorrecto incluir la clase "**class.smtp.php**" de forma manual y se debía hacer mediante el Autoload a lo que intente con el autoload "`PHPMailerAutoload.php`", el resultado fue el mismo donde se queda colgada la petición y no envía nada.

¿Alguien sabrá que es lo que pueda estar ocurriendo?

Éste es mi código, las lineas comentadas son intentos y combinaciones que estuve realizando, solo deje la parte donde se me queda colgado con el autoload

```
    $nombre=htmlspecialchars($_POST['nombre']);
    $email=htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
    $asunto=htmlspecialchars($_POST['asunto']);
    $mensaje=$_POST['mensaje'];

    require ("../phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

    // include ("../phpmailer/class.smtp.php");
    // include ("../phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");

    // require_once ("../phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
    // include ("../phpmailer/class.smtp.php");

    // require ("../phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
    // require ("../phpmailer/class.smtp.php");

    $mail=new PHPMailer;
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth=true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Host='smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port='465';
    $mail->Username='micorreo@mail.com';
    $mail->Password='mipass';       
    $mail->From='micorreo@mail.com';
    $mail->FromName='Administrador';
    $mail->Subject=$asunto;
    $mail->AddAddress($email,$nombre);
    $mail->MsgHTML($mensaje);

    if($mail->Send())
    {
        $msg='Se ha enviado el mensaje a '.$email;
    }
    else
    {
        $msg='Ha habido un error al enviar el correo a '.$email;
        echo 'Error Mail '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
```

Por otro lado la parte del php.ini la tengo con estos cambios que no le veo problema salvo que este pasando por alto algún detalle:

```
[mail function]  
SMTP=localhost:8012  
smtp_port=465
```

Gracias y saludos